# Changed Android Permission in Application Settings Listener

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to create an event listener in application settings for permission?
Kindly, refer to this image for clarification.
[image: Need an event listener so i will be able to trigger my dialog]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such callback in android for global settings change, but in your code you can check if you have permission to access certain resource before proceeding further. (app's target SDK is 23 or higher)

Check http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

**Asking user for permission at runtime**

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for this information also if you guys got confused to my question you refer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958449/android-marshmallow-callback-when-user-revokes-permissions-from-settings

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for this information also if you guys got confused to my question you can refer to this one [Android Marshmallow Callback when user revokes permissions from settings ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958449/android-marshmallow-callback-when-user-revokes-permissions-from-settings)