# Different inspection behavior between two IDEA projects

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-permissions, code-inspection

I'm having a strange issue with inspections in a project that I created only a few days ago in IDEA 2016.3.3, which I upgraded to 2016.3.5 when I encountered this issue.  The problem persists in the older project even after invalidating caches and restarting.  I cannot reproduce it in a new project created in 2016.3.5.

Both projects have the same `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion`, and `buildToolsVersion`.  **What else could cause this difference in inspection behavior?**

I created an identical class in both projects:

```
public class PermissionWeirdness {    
    public void foo() {
        bar();
        baz();
    }

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    private void bar() {}

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void baz() {}
}
```

- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `GET_ACCOUNTS` are both classified as "dangerous" permissions.
- In both projects, as expected, warnings appear in `foo()` on the calls to `bar()` and `baz()`.
- In the newer project, both warnings have the same form:

  > Missing permission required by PermissionWeirdness.bar: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- In the older project, the warning related to `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` has a completely different message.  The tooltip text has literal backticks in it that are interpreted here as code tags:

  > Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available ( with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`
- In both projects, the warnings that take the shorter form can be eliminated by adding the appropriate `@RequiresPermission` annotation to `foo()`.
- In the older project, the mysterious longer warning *cannot* be eliminated in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the real project and my attempt to reproduce the issue in a sample project was in the manifest.  **The behavior of the inspection changes for dangerous permissions**, but only when they are listed in the manifest.  The warning message changes, and `@RequiresPermission` no longer cascades.

I originally thought this was a regression of [Android Studio bug 177281](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177381), but that issue was more general.  Not cascading for dangerous permissions may have been intentional, but I've reported it as a bug because [the process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32958485/1953590) if the user revokes a permission from a running app.